# Wildcard route in Grape

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

I'm having issues getting [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) to respond to a purely wild card route.

By that I mean that if I have a simple route defined as

```
get do
...
end
```

I need to respond to all potential requests made to the API. The situation being I need to parse the path and params and then work through a decision tree based on those values.

I've tried a few variations on the route definition, such as:

```
get '/*' do
...
end

get '/(*)' do
...
end
```

But to no avail.

I know that there is some support for regular expressions and route anchoring in Grape, but I've had no luck figuring it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close with the guess at the syntax, you just need to name the matching param:

E.g.

```
  get '*thing' do
    { :thing => params[:thing] }
  end
```

Using the `*` will make the param capture the rest of the URI path, ignoring `/` separators. But otherwise it behaves just like any other param.

Note this will only pickup within the Rack mount point at best, so if you have

```
  prefix      'api'
  version     'v2'
```

then it will respond to paths like `/api/v2/hkfhqk/fwggw/ewfewg`

If you are using this for custom 404 or other catch-all routes, then you need to add it at the end, otherwise it will mask more specific routes.