# Grape with dynamic route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

I have a requirement where user can pass url in this format:

`http:site.com/[action]/[subject]?[option]=[value]`

for example all of the below are valid urls:

```
http://example.com/trigger/a/b/c
http://example.com/trigger/a
http://example.com/trigger/a/b?something=value
http://example.com/trigger/any/thing/goes/here
```

I have a `grape` resource like this:

```
class Test < Grape::API
  params do
    optional :option, type: String
  end

  get '/trigger/:a/:b/:c' do
    {
      type: 'trigger',
      a: params[:a],
      b: params[:b],
      c: params[:c],
      option: params[:option]
    }
  end
end
```

So, If I visit `http://example.com/1/2/3/option=something` then I will get

```
{
  "type": "trigger",
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "3",
  "option": "something"
}
```

Expected Behavior:

Use should be able to provide anything after `/trigger/`

```
http://example.com/any/thing/goes/here/1/2/3?other=value&goes=here
```

*Update:*

I found this solution ([How do we identify parameters in a dynamic URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690298/how-do-we-identify-parameters-in-a-dynamic-url#)) for rails route, I want this behavior in `grape`.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I was looking for `wildcards` with `matching params`

```
get "trigger/*subject" do
  {
    params: params[:subject]
  }
end
```

Now it will respond to path like:

```
curl http://example.com/trigger/subject/can/be/anything
```

Output:

```
{
 params: "subject/can/be/anything"
}
```

Thanks to Neil's answer 
[Wildcard route in Grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650832/wildcard-route-in-grape)